# file vs. memory mismatch on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have set up Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

After upgrading from VirtualBox 6.0.22-13798 0to VirtualBox 6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2)

> NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: Unknown Status -5600 (0xffffea20 (rcNt=0xe986ea20)
> VBoxDrvStub error: ntdll.dll: 11 differences between 0xa0492 and 0xa049c in #1 (.text), first:8b != b8 (rc =-5600

> Make sure the kernel module has been loaded successfully.

> where: supR3HardenedWinReSpawn what: 3 VERR_SUP_VP_MEMORY_VS_FILE_MISMATCH (-5600) - Process Verification Failure: The memory content does not match the image file.

But WHAT kernel module? WHAT file?

Answer (score 0):

If your root OS and VBOX is installed on windows . . .  close Virtual Box.  Go to C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv directory.  Right click on VBoxDrv.inf and select install.  Restart the VBOXDRV service or open command prompt and type 'sc start vboxdrv' then try starting the Ubuntu VM.

Comment: In command prompt (AS ADMINISTRATOR).  Nice answer.. I was about to submit this as a comment but you clearly need the points.  If and when Blas accepts, I will +1.  Fix your answer to include the admin comment and I will delete this comment.  Also, there are a handful of other possible causes.. I hope this fixes it for Blas.